# Unable to access windows controls inside pywinauto's hwndwrapper (wrapper class

Tags: python, wrapper, pywinauto

I am new to python and pywinauto. Trying to set or get Text for TextBox (windows control) inside pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.hwndwrapper by using SWAPY, I have Class Name of wrapper class. How to access controls inside wrapper class using class name (like `Afx:633C0000:1008`) in pywinauto?

```
import pywinauto
import pywinauto.controls
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().Connect(title=u'SAP', class_name='SAP_FRONTEND_SESSION')
sapfrontendsession = app.SAP
afxe = sapfrontendsession[u'Afx:633C0000:1008']
```

[image]

Comment: share your code snippet. It will help others to understand your problem quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pywinauto provides a 2-level concept based on `WindowSpecification` and wrappers. Window specification is just a description, set of criteria to search desired control (it may not exist when `WindowSpecification` is created). Concrete wrapper is created for really existing control if found. In IDLE console it looks so:

```
>>> app.RowListSampleApplication
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x0000000003859B38>
>>> app.RowListSampleApplication.wrapper_object()
<pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004ADF780>
```

Window specification can have no more than 2 levels: `app.WindowName.ControlName`. It can be specified with more detailed search criteria:

```
app.window(title=u'SAP', class_name_re='^Afx:.*$')
app.SAP.child_window(class_name='Edit')
```

Possible `window/child_window` arguments are the same as listed in [find_elements](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html#pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements).

---

P.S. Great Python features can hide `wrapper_object()` method call in production code so you need to call it for debugging purpose only. For example these statements are equivalent (do the same):

```
app.WindowName.Edit.set_text(u'text')
app.WindowName.Edit.wrapper_object().set_text(u'text')
```

But the statements below return different objects:

```
app.WindowName.Edit # <WindowSpecification>
app.WindowName.Edit.wrapper_object() # <EditWrapper>
```

Comment: vasily,Child window has two textbox and button.when i tried to get controls,I only get this child class details as below:

    c=app.SAP.ChildWindow(class_name='Afx:633C0000:1008')
    c.PrintControlIdentifiers()

In console,

    Control Identifiers:
Afx:633C0000:1008 - ''   (L21, T141, R1345, B696)
 '11' 'Afx:633C0000:1008' ()

Comment: `PrintControlIdentifiers()` is useful for top-level windows only. For the control you always will have this control info in the output.

Comment: Use `app.SAP.PrintControlIdentifiers()` to get all controls on the form.

Comment: It doesn't give controls inside Afx:633C0000:1008 class.                                       Button - ''   (L34, T113, R128, B133)
 '9' 'Button' ()
Afx:633C0000:8:00010003:00000010:00000000 - ''   (L24, T696, R1348, B728)
 '10' 'Afx:633C0000:8:00010003:00000010:00000000' ()
Afx:633C0000:1008 - ''   (L24, T141, R1348, B696)
 '11' 'Afx:633C0000:1008' ()

Comment: Probably the application is not native and pywinauto cannot detect some controls on the form. Try to run `Inspect.exe` in the `UI Automation` mode. Can be found here: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\inspect.exe"`

Comment: i didn't have in my system (windows 7 32 bit).How can i get inspect.exe?

Comment: OK, it should be here: `"C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\inspect.exe"`

Comment: Usually Visual Studio includes `Inspect.exe` but you can find it in the Internet to download separately. Or copy from another machine that has dev. environment installed.

Comment: By using inspect.exe,I have set focus on username and Password Textbox but except Mouse Move property ,all the other properties are same.I dont have any idea how to access those controls. vasily, i will attach screenshot of screen for your reference

Comment: It would be interesting to take a look at the screenshot. )

Comment: FI, the link is broken.

Comment: @Syscall thanks! I've updated answer with fresh link and method names.